# Bypassing WS_CLIPCHILDREN

Tags: c++, winapi

I have create a custom scroll bar with transparency option. The way this transparency works is very simple, I invalidate the required region and let the parent to erase and paint itself, after that I repaint the scroll bar itself. Here's some piece of code:

```
void Refresh(bool bForceOwnerRedraw)
    {
        if (Gui.OwnerRedraw || bForceOwnerRedraw)
            InvalidateBackgroundRegion(State.CurrentState);

        RedrawWindow(Gui.OwnerWindow, &Gui.DrawingRectangle, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_NOERASE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);
    }

void InvalidateBackgroundRegion(DWORD State)
    {
        HWND hWndParent = GetParent(Gui.OwnerWindow);
        POINT p = {0};

        MapWindowPoints(Gui.OwnerWindow, hWndParent, &p, 1);

        HRGN BackGroundRegion = CreateRectRgn(Gui.DrawingRectangle.left + p.x, Gui.DrawingRectangle.top + p.y, Gui.DrawingRectangle.right + p.x, Gui.DrawingRectangle.bottom + p.y);
        HRGN MainRegion = NULL;

        if (State & SELECTED || State & SELECTED_HOVER)
        {
            int Width = Gui.DrawingRectangle.left + Position.SelectedState.MainDrawing.right + p.x + 1,
                Height = Gui.DrawingRectangle.top + Position.SelectedState.MainDrawing.bottom + p.y + 1;

            MainRegion = CreateRoundRectRgn(Position.SelectedState.MainDrawing.left + Gui.DrawingRectangle.left + p.x, Position.SelectedState.MainDrawing.top + Gui.DrawingRectangle.top + p.y, Width, Height, Gui.uiCornerRoundness, Gui.uiCornerRoundness);
        }
        else if (State & UNSELECTED || State & UNSELECTED_HOVER)
        {
            int Width = Gui.DrawingRectangle.left + Position.UnselectedState.MainDrawing.right + p.x + 1,
                Height = Gui.DrawingRectangle.top + Position.UnselectedState.MainDrawing.bottom + p.y + 1;

            MainRegion = CreateRoundRectRgn(Position.UnselectedState.MainDrawing.left+Gui.DrawingRectangle.left+p.x, Position.UnselectedState.MainDrawing.top+Gui.DrawingRectangle.top+p.y, Width, Height, Gui.uiCornerRoundness, Gui.uiCornerRoundness);
        }
        else if (State & INTERMEDIATE || State & INTERMEDIATE_HOVER)
        {
            int Width = Gui.DrawingRectangle.left + Position.IntermediateState.MainDrawing.right + p.x + 1,
                Height = Gui.DrawingRectangle.top + Position.IntermediateState.MainDrawing.bottom + p.y + 1;

            MainRegion = CreateRoundRectRgn(Position.IntermediateState.MainDrawing.left + Gui.DrawingRectangle.left + p.x, Position.IntermediateState.MainDrawing.top + Gui.DrawingRectangle.top + p.y, Width, Height, Gui.uiCornerRoundness, Gui.uiCornerRoundness);
        }
        CombineRgn(BackGroundRegion, BackGroundRegion, MainRegion, RGN_DIFF);
        RedrawWindow(hWndParent, NULL, BackGroundRegion, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT);

        DeleteObject(MainRegion);
        DeleteObject(BackGroundRegion);
    }
```

The problem occurs when I resize the main window, everything flickers. However I can prevent that by using `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag on main window, but then my scroll bar looses it's transparency, because I no longer can't invalidate parts, that are owned by child windows.

What I have tried so far:

1. Before invalidating parent, I removed `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag, repainted, and then set `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` flag back. [Result: It worked, however my CPU usage went over 30%, so it's a no no.]
2. Tried validating child windows (without `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`), before erasing and repainting. 
   [Result: didn't work, don't know why... maybe I... nope no idea.]
3. Completely disabled all repainting in my scroll bar (without `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`) [Result: didn't work, still flickers.]

What I would like to achieve here is to find a way to to bypass WS_CLIPCHILDREN by invalidating window manually (maybe somehow invalidating using SendMessage() to bypass it). Any other suggestion are also welcome. Thanks

EDIT:

Some more information about how I create my scroll bar. In the code below you can see that my scroll bar is just an empty child window with `WS_VISIBLE` and `WS_CHILD` flags, all of the painting is done using good old gdi.

```
void RegisterScrollbarClass()
    {
        if (RegisteredClasses.bCustomScrollBar)
            return;

        WNDCLASSEX wc;

        wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc   = BaseWindow::stWinMsgHandler;
        wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        wc.hInstance     = NULL;
        wc.hIcon         = NULL;
        wc.hCursor       = NULL;
        wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
        wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("CUSTOM_SCROLLBAR");
        wc.hIconSm       = NULL;

        if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Button Class Registration Failed!"), TEXT("ERROR!"), MB_ICONERROR);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        RegisteredClasses.bCustomScrollBar = true;
    }

HWND CreateScrollbar(DWORD dwExStyle, LPCTSTR lpClassName, LPCTSTR lpWindowName, DWORD dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, HWND hWndParent, HMENU hMenu, HINSTANCE hInstance, LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        DWORD ScrollbarStyle = NULL, Child = NULL;

        if ((dwStyle & SB_VERT) == SB_VERT)
            ScrollbarStyle = SB_VERT;
        else if ((dwStyle & SB_HORZ) == SB_HORZ)
            ScrollbarStyle = SB_HORZ;
        else
            return NULL;

        if ((dwStyle & WS_CHILD) == WS_CHILD)
            Child = WS_CHILD;
        if ((dwStyle & WS_VISIBLE) == WS_VISIBLE)
            Child |= WS_VISIBLE;

        RegisterScrollbarClass();

        Scrollbar.push_back(CustomScrollbar(ScrollbarStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, (int)hMenu));
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Scrollbar.size(); i++)
            Scrollbar.at(i).Create();

        if (Scrollbar.at(Scrollbar.size()-1).Create(dwExStyle, lpClassName, NULL, Child, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam) != NULL)
        {
            if (Scrollbar.size() == 2)
                Scrollbar.at(Scrollbar.size() - 1).EnableTransparent(true);
            return Scrollbar.at(Scrollbar.size()-1).WindowHandle();
        }
        else
        {
            Scrollbar.pop_back();
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

---

Here you can download sample program: http://www.putlocker.com/file/B8704C613BC7EC96

---

SOLVED:

Thanks to Raymond Chen, I have removed `CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW` from my Scroll bar class and I works like a charm without `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`.

Comment: `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` is also pretty incompatible with the transparency of a "group box" (button with `BS_GROUP`somethingsomething style). Just an observation.

Comment: That is not my problem, I only have WS_VISIBLE and WS_CHILD flags. I added some of my code to explain what I mean. My scroll bar is simply just a lonely window :)

Comment: The flickering is coming from `CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW` and the fact that you are composing on screen instead of off-screen.

Comment: Wow, I have no words... I thought I checked `CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW` and it didn't work, but I was wrong. Thank you! And Merry Christmas :)